# NPN BJT transistor large signal model

Tags: semiconductor-physics

[image]

which of the following is valid forward active mode large signal model of npn bjt transistor ,here a),b) similar and c),d) are similar I want to know a) or c) which of them is best and valid equivalent to npn bjt, I think for me circuit A) makes more sense because in actual npn bjt both Ic and Ib current passes through the BE junction but in lot of textbooks model C) was used , I dont but how does C) is valid. can anyone clarify my doubt .

Comment: This seems more suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

None of them is valid since none of them captures the vanishing, or even reversal, of collector current if the collector-emitter voltage becomes zero or negative.

If you had asked about small-signal behavior then the models might be suitable (as crude models!) But the title explicitly mentions large-signal behavior...